# ¿Cómo mostrar una columna de datos en varias columnas con bash?

Tags: linux, bash, procesamiento-de-texto

Mi idea era mostrar el contenido del primer campo (el usuario) del fichero /etc/passwd, que originalmente se muestra de forma de columna con un usuario por fila, sin el resto de información (o sea solo el usuario) y no en forma de columna de nombres, sino en forma de varias columnas para que sean visibles todos juntos de un vistazo.

Lo más que he conseguido para agrupar los resultados en un formato más compacto es este alias que pasa la columna de nombres por el comando fmt:

```
alias lsusers='cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | fmt'
```

El resultado es algo como esto:

```
$ lsusers 
root daemon bin sys sync games man lp mail news uucp proxy www-data    backup
etc.. etc.. etc.. etc.. etc.. etc.. etc..
etc.. etc.. etc.. etc.. etc.. etc.. etc.. etc..
$
```

Lo que busco es algo más parecido a esto:

```
root      games      proxy       etc..
daemon    man        www-data    etc..
bin       mail       backup
sys       news       etc..
sync      uucp       etc..
```

Mi pregunta es:
¿Existe algún comando que me permita formatear la salida de de mi alias a un formato de varias columnas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `column -t` para mostrar los datos en columnas. Si previamente le indicas con `paste` cuántos campos quieres por línea, ya lo tienes.

Por ejemplo, esto sería con tres columnas (especificado con los tres "-" de `paste - - -`):

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | paste - - - | column -t
```

Con tu salida de ejemplo, tendríamos:

```
root      daemon  bin
sys       sync    games
man       lp      mail
news      uucp    proxy
www-data  backup
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que buscaba, gracias.